# Low quality question with over evaluated votes

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, upvotes

The post [Issue with recording from the Open ONVIF (Network Video Interface Forum ) device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20986661/issue-with-recording-from-open-network-video-interface-forum-onvif-device) have lots of votes compare to the quality of the question. The question will not help anybody to understand ONVIF recording interface because it involve code that is not in the post.

I downvotes and flag it twice but a moderator removed some comments speaking about the excessive promotion of the post.

Several people ask for additional information without answers...

What could be done in order to reduce the votes that seems to indicate this is an interesting question ?

Comment: _abusive votes?_ Maybe I'm not seeing it but how is this abusive?

Comment: you are right "abusive" is not the right term, perhaps over evaluated votes ?

Comment: You can downvote it if you think it's a bad question. People will often upvote when they run across an unanswered question that they'd also like to see the answer to.

Comment: I still don't fully understand the issue, people can vote as they like. The question has been viewed 1.5k+ times in 5 months, possibly people feel the question is worthy of the votes.

Comment: That's what seems strange, the question is probably referenced and then view a lot. But the question does not explain the problem, does not show research effort and will probably stay forever open...

Comment: 'This account is temporarily suspended for voting irregularities. The suspension period ends on Mar 4 at 16:50.', then perhaps someone else notice something...

Answer (score 3):

> What could be done in order to reduce the votes that seems to indicate this is an interesting question?

If you think the question isn't good, downvote it. But that's all. You're not going to change how other users evaluate the post. If they think it's useful, clear or otherwise deserving of an upvote, they are free to vote so.

This is not really something a moderator needs to get involved in. But who knows, maybe the attention you're giving it here will have the Meta users evaluate it differently.

Answer (score 3):

> The question will not help anybody to understand ONVIF recording

That was not the point of the question, it documented a problem that a programmer encountered while using ONVIF.  This is entirely normal, questions are not expected to be tutorials and a basic understanding of ONVIF is assumed by the questioner.  Appropriately, nobody can answer this question if they don't know the basics of ONVIF.

> Several people ask for additional information without answers

That's a strong explanation for why the question is popular.  Apparently lots of programmers have the same issue when using ONVIF.  A well-written and well-documented *single* question is sufficient to get such an issue exposed.  This question plays that role and saves everybody from having to ask their own question about the same issue.  It is a *canonical* question, something we strongly strive for at SO.

That the question doesn't have a useful answer is entirely normal as well.  There is no warranty here, nobody can guarantee that an issue is solvable.  Some day, *somebody* is going to write the canonical answer to this canonical question.  A good way to make that day arrive soon is to put a bounty on the question.

Comment: This is what I feel strange, it make believe that lots of programmers have the same issue. In such a case they share the same code that should be shared in the question, isn't it ?